# Convert PHP image resource identifier to html <img> element

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here goes.

I have a directory full of image files that I need to read using PHP.  I then need to turn them into html img elements to be used in a gallery.

I am linked this page (http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm) to use as reference on this assignment.  It shows an example using imagecreatefromjpeg(), imagecreatefrompng(), and imagecreatefromgif():

**sample code**

```
// this is just example only

$imgfile = $rsPhoto['photo']; // or value from database

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgfile);

switch ($type) 
{

case 1: $im = imagecreatefromgif($imgfile); 
header("Content-type: image/gif"); 
break;

case 2:  
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile); 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
break;

case 3: 
$im = imagecreatefrompng($imgfile); 
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
break;

}
```

I don't understand what it's doing at all.  Somehow it gets some kind of weird php object file, then...displays it as the whole page?  Where/how/why does it do this?

Below is what I WANT the page to do.  createGalleryEl doesn't work, gives me errors telling me the file doesn't exist.  Is this because of my .htaccess file?

**gallery.php**

```
<?php

//Create the basic headers, etc.
echo "<head>"
        ."<title>Photo Gallery</title>"
        .'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">'
        .'<meta charset="UTF-8">'
    ."</head>";

echo "<body>";
echo "<h1>Photo Gallery</h1>";
echo "<div id='gallery'>";

/*Get all files in uploads.  Check if they're image files.  If they are,
  create gallery elements for them with thumbnails and all. */
$files1 = scandir("uploads/");

foreach($files1 as $thisFile) {
    $whitelist = array(".png", ".gif", "jpg", ".jpeg");
    foreach ($whitelist as $file) {
        if(preg_match("/$file\$/i", $thisFile)) {
            //Create the gallery element for it.
            createGalleryEl($thisFile);
        }
    }
}

echo '</div>'; //end of gallery
echo '</body>';

//Creates the actual element for the gallery.
function createGalleryEl($filename) {
    echo "<div class='thumbnail'><img src='uploads/$filename'></div>";
}

?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
php_flag allow_url_fopen On 
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

**Given this setup, how can I take the image files and put them into html img elements?**

Also, if I'm totally misunderstanding something about how this kind of thing works, please tell me.  I'm not used to PHP and server-side development as a whole at all, so I probably have lapses in my knowledge in most of this stuff.

Comment: i don't see why you need imagecreatefromgif(etc) at all

Comment: Isn't it because I can't link directly to the files themselves (because I've restricted it in the .htaccess file for security reasons)?  Is there a way to do it while still using those functions?

Comment: Ok, more crucial question:  With the above .htaccess file, can I somehow get the images to show up in an html img element?  In any possible way?

Comment: what do you think your protecting them from?

Comment: protecting them from having people run scripts on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to protect the original image directory with .htaccess, you can create images on the fly using the PHP GD library (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

The barebones of your script will work, but because you have denied access to the image source directory, the images won't load in the browser.

The workaround involves calling a script in an allowed directory with an identifier to load a certain image.

**Example:**

**image.php**

```
    <?php

    // Set allowable array
    $allowableImages = [];

    // Find files in the directory - you can reuse your existing method to check if the file exists and is in the whitelist
    // Alternatively you could pull this information from a database or just set a manual array

    $files = scandir("uploads/");

    foreach($files as $thisFile) {
        $whitelist = array(".png", ".gif", "jpg", ".jpeg");
        foreach ($whitelist as $file) {
            if(preg_match("/$file\$/i", $thisFile)) {

                $allowableImages[] = $thisFile;

            }

        }

    }

    // Get the image name from GET
    $image = $_GET["i"];

    // Create the image if it is in the array
    if(in_array($image, $allowableImages)) {

        $imgfile = "uploads/" . $image;

        // Get image size attributes
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgfile);

        switch ($type) {

            case 1:
                $im = imagecreatefromgif($imgfile);
                header("Content-type: image/gif");
                imagegif($im);
                break;

            case 2:
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile);
                header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($im);
                break;

            case 3:
                $im = imagecreatefrompng($imgfile);
                header("Content-type: image/png");
                imagepng($im);
                break;

        }

        // Destroy image resource
        imagedestroy($im);

    }

?>
```

And then in your gallery.php file, simply update the createGalleryEl function:

```
//Creates the actual element for the gallery.
function createGalleryEl($filename) {
    echo "<div class='thumbnail'><img src='image.php?i=$filename'></div>";
}
```

Comment: Extending on from this - you could also resize the image into a thumbnail. So the gallery could display a thumbnail version and when you click the image have it bring up a full version. Take a look at [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). I would pass another get variable say "t" to trigger the image resize to produce a thumbnail.

Comment: You could also use a data URL.

Comment: @Anthony Yes definitely - a more simple solution too! Only thing would be backwards compability with older browsers.

Comment: Great - glad it helped!